# Handle complex request formats and return response

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building an API using Django rest framework. My API has to receive complex requests that are somewhat different from my models. More specifically the request has to include fields that do not exist in my models.

As an example I have included one of the models and the request that will be received by the API.

```
from django.db import model

class Author(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=False)
    birth_year = mmodels.CharField(max_length=9, blank=False)
```

and the json request is

```
{
    "general": {
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
    },
    "details": [
        "1980"
    ]
}
```

How can I parse that request efficiently, store the data in my database and finally return a response similar to the request?

---

My approach so far is to create a serializer like the following and modify its `create()` and `to_represent()` methods, however this approach seems very dirty especially with **nested** relationships.

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    general = serializers.DictField(write_only=True)
    details = serializers.ListField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = [
            "id", "general", "details",
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author_data = {}
        author_data['first_name'] = validated_data['general']['name']
        author_data['last_name'] = validated_data['general']['surname']
        author_data['birth_year'] = validated_data['details'][0]

        author = Author.objects.create(**author_data) 
        return author_data 

    def to_representation(self, instance):

        final_representation = OrderedDict()

        final_representation["id"] = instance.id
        final_representation["general"] = {}
        final_representation["general"]["name"] = instance.first_name
        final_representation["general"]["surname"] = instance.last_name

        final_representation["details"] = [instance.birth_year]
        
        return final_representation
```

Comment: how are you using this ? please share your `views.py` too ? also what is `WritableNestedModelSerializer` ?

Comment: What do you mean  with 'extract json fields'? Your models don´t have `HStoreField()` or `JsonField()`. Do you mean you want to display data that isn´t `null`/`None` and fields that are `None` shall be hid ?

Comment: @Klim Bim I mean the json fields of the request. Some of the request fields corespondent to a model while others do not. I would like to make the serilizer clear the non-model fields and parse the others

Comment: @Charalamm Did you override `to_representation()` or where do get the keys `type, properties....`? They aren´t part of your model. Your json request you mentioned, is it the data you want to store?

Comment: @KlimBim No I haven't overridden `to_representation()`. I will try to do it now. Yes some "sub"-fields like `app_one, app_two, ..., soft_two` have the data I want to store. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @Charalamm I got it. You get the json data from a different server as a response and you want to extract these data to fit into your mode? Either you can override `to_internal()` and extract the data you want or do it before you add the data to your serializer `ApplicationSerializer(data=<data_you_wanto_to_store>)`. Let me know if you need an instruction/walkthrough.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it!! I get the json data from a different server as a *request* and I actually have to return the same data with a couple of more fields. I will edit to add the response I have to give. I will also read about `to_internal()`. Thanks again!